# Trouble scraping for specific html data, or data just not showing

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, jsoup

Hello to the community.

I am experiencing a problem when attempting to collect  and  element objects, from deep within the html body of the site which I am scraping.

Url.

https://corporation.directory/quicksearch/company

Inside my AsynTask.DoInBackground method, I have the following.

```
        try {


            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://corporation.directory/quicksearch/company").get();

            for (Element table : doc.select("body"))
            {
                for (Element row : table.select("table.0")){

                    tds = row.select("td");
                    if (tds.size() > 0){

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tds.get(0).text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }


           // title=doc.body().text();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the data I have been unsuccessfully trying to retrieve
[I am trying to retrieve multiple  elements with text, that contains these identifiers (Twitter, Colorado,(303)-444-4444, Alex Oha)][ Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated]

screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/quAgl.png

Answer (score 0):

The page it self doesn't return any resulst if you make a GET request, you need to make a POST...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://corporation.directory/quicksearch/company")
.data("name", "market")
.data("city", "")
.data("state", "")
.data("search", "true")
.post();
```

Comment: I am gaining some understanding now.. Would you kindly use some of the data I have provided as data queries? I would like to gain a deeper understanding as to how, for an example, you could retrieve data for name and city from the data I have provided..